# Objective-C memory leak in C methods

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, memory, object, methods

Hi all
I get memory leaks on the leaks instrument whenever I trigger this method. Do you think anything is wrong with this??

```
static NSString* readStringOrDie(InputData *input, size_t length, NSStringEncoding encoding) 
{
    NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes: readOrDie(input,length) 
                                         length: length
                                       encoding: encoding]; // HERE THE LEAK COMES !!
    if (!str)
        [NSException raise: BERParserException format: @"Unparseable string"];

    return [str autorelease];
}
```

Comment: Nothing looks wrong there check readOrDie and make sure a NSAutoReleasePool is setup.

Comment: Show readOrDie() and the context where this method gets called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That code is fine. Most likely the actor that receives str retains it and subsequently fails to release it. Instruments knows where memory that has leaked was allocated but doesn't know where it should have been released, so it can provide some slightly unhelpful clues.

Comment: +1 the leak is not *here*, but the memory that was leaked was allocated here.

Answer (score 0):

Because of using NSException for recoverable error.